# Why is OpenCL in cpp using 0xdeadbeef?

Tags: c++, opencl

In this [HandsOnOpenCL example](https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL/Exercises-Solutions/blob/master/Solutions/Exercise04/Cpp/vadd_chain.cpp), they use something like the following to declare vectors.

```
std::vector<float> h_a(LENGTH);                // a vector 
std::vector<float> h_b(LENGTH);                // b vector  
std::vector<float> h_c (LENGTH, 0xdeadbeef);   // c vector (result)
```

The only one which uses 0xdeadbeef is the *result vector*. But I have no idea why. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's just an easy to remember hexadecimal number.

Comment: yeah, but what does it mean? is it useful?

Comment: It's a debugging/diagnostic aid: if you look at the contents of `h_c` in a debugger, and see `0xdeadbeef`, then you know that (almost certainly) that value hasn't been changed since the vector was constructed.

Comment: Ok, it's used only as a reference right? But it doesn't affect anything? Because in the example of the link, they have 3 *0xdeadbeef* vectors declared and they only change the values of one.

Comment: And, as well as all of the above, it has a certain nerdy cool factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCL in general doesn't use this value for anything.  This particular example of using OpenCL uses `0xdeadbeef` to initialize a few vectors.  It does this so that you can verify the result of the computation with this well-known value.

Whenever you see this value, it is most certainly being used for debugging or verification purposes.  If the value isn't changed during execution of the program, then you know for sure that something went wrong and there's a bug to be fixed.

Comment: I just freaked out because I've never seen that before =), thanks.

Comment: 0xBADC0DE is pretty common too.

Comment: @black So is `0xcafebabe`. I also recently found `0xabad1dea`.